# Convert String to Date then to timestamp to add to firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Okay so I've got two react native componenet DateTimePicker that I use to collect a date and time from the user using the following on change func

```js
 const onChangeDate = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    setDateShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
    setDate(currentDate);

    let tempDate = new Date(currentDate);
    let date = tempDate.getFullYear() + '-' + tempDate.getMonth() + '-' + tempDate.getDate();

    console.log(date); //2022-4-18
    setFinalDate(date);
  }
  const onChangeTime = (event, selectedTime) => {
    const currentTime = selectedTime || time;
    setTimeShow(Platform.OS === 'ios');
    setTime(currentTime);

    let tempDate = new Date(currentTime);

    let time = tempDate.getHours() + ':' + tempDate.getMinutes() + ':' + tempDate.getSeconds() + tempDate.getMilliseconds();

    console.log(time); //0:10:00
    setFinalTime(time);
  }
```

After setting a state for finalTime and finalDate

```js
const eventTimestamp = (`${finalDate} ${finalTime}`); 
console.log(eventTimestamp) // output is 2022-4-18 0:10:00
```

I cant seem to convert this into a date() object and then into a timestamp using toMillis() method becuse I want to add this into firestore as a timestamp.
Converting it into a date using new Date() gives me **Date { NaN }** and using firestore method firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(works) gives me **Object {
"nanoseconds": NaN,
"seconds": NaN,
}**

Any luck on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should parse the date string then convert it into a `date()` object. See sample code below:

```
// Initiate a new Date object.
const eventTimestamp = new Date(
  // Parse the string into a date
  Date.parse(
    `${finalDate} ${finalTime}`
    )
)

await setDoc(doc(db, "<collection>", "<document-id>"), {
    timestamp: eventTimestamp
});
```

For more information, you may checkout this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).